# JavaFX 11: "JavaFX runtime components are missing"

Tags: java, javafx, jgrasp, javafx-11

I'm trying to run sample JavaFX code (taken from the 5th edition of Java Illuminated) under JavaFX 11 and Java 11, using jGRASP 2 under Windows 10.

I've read through the "Getting Started with JavaFX" guide (https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) extensively, and while I've made some progress, I'm stuck.

I've downloaded the latest ZIP file, unpacked it, and updated the CLASSPATH to include a path to the jar files needed to compile.   I can successfully compile the file.   However, when I try to run, I get the following error message:

> Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

The "Getting Started" guide says that this can be fixed by adding the following options to the runtime call:

> --module-path "[path]\lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml

I've added the options, but I'm still getting the error message.

Previous StackOverflow articles usually end with the option setting above; alas, I can't figure out what else to do.

Comment: In the runtime options did you change the path to point the folder with the JavaFX library: `"[path]\lib"` Additional question: When you say you added the classpath to include the jar, did you add it to the windows classpath, or the IDE classpath?

Comment: 1) Yes, [path] is replaced by the actual path to the library --- in my case, literally "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib"

Comment: 2) I changed the IDE classpath.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a first time user, I've managed to make it work, but it was not straightforward to me.

I guess there are no many people familiarized with this IDE, so I'm going to post the steps I followed, as a basic tutorial:

- [Download](https://spider.eng.auburn.edu/user-cgi/grasp/grasp.pl?;dl=download_jgrasp.html) and install jGRASP version 2.0.5_05 Beta.
- Since I have a few JDKs installed, it selected by default JDK 10.0.2, so my first step was to find a way to work with JDK 11. That can be done in `Settings -> jGrasp Startup Settings`, where I can set the path for my `java` executable:

[image: SetJDK 11]

Then I restarted jGrasp. You can verify which JDK the IDE is using in `Tools -> System Info -> Java Version`.

- Open HelloFX sample class. I've started with the most basic sample from [the OpenJFX docs](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx). The code can be found [here](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/blob/master/HelloFX/CLI/hellofx/HelloFX.java).
- `Build -> compile`, as expected, will throw a bunch of errors given that JavaFX is no longer part of the JDK:

[image: Compile fails]

- Following the OpenJFX docs, we need to download the JavaFX SDK from [here](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/), and then add the library to the classpath. Go to `Settings -> PATH/CLASSPATH -> Workspace`, press New, and add, one by one, the different JavaFX jars from the downloaded SDK/lib folder (at least `javafx-base.jar`, `javafx-graphics.jar` and `javafx-controls.jar`).
- `Build -> compile` should work now.
- Next step: `Build -> Run`. This fails:

```
----jGRASP exec: java HelloFX
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

 ----jGRASP wedge: exit code for process is 1.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

That was expected. According to the docs, we need to set the module-path and add-modules arguments.

- First attempt: use `Run arguments`. After setting:

```
--module-path /Users/<user>/Downloads/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib --add-modules javafx.controls
```

running again failed with the exact same error message as above, but with one difference in the console log:

```
----jGRASP exec: java HelloFX --module-path /Users/<user>/Downloads/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib --add-modules javafx.controls
```

What's wrong with that!? Well... if you try that on command line, it will fail as well, because the order of arguments is wrong, the vm arguments should go *before* the class name.

In conclusion: `Run arguments` are not `VM arguments`!

- Second attempt: In order to provide the VM arguments, the option I found was to edit `Settings -> Compiler settings -> Workspace`. By default, it is using `jdk (integrated debugger) - generic`. You can view it and see that for `Run` it uses:

```
java %S -ea %S %<FLAGS2> %<MAIN_CLASS> %<ARGS>
```

So instead of `ARGS` we need to find a way to set `FLAGS2`.

Luckily, next to the `Environment` tab, there is a `Flags/Args` tab, and there we can set our vm arguments in `FLAGS2`:

```
--module-path /Users/<user>/Downloads/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib --add-modules javafx.controls
```

[image: VM args]

- Apply, close the dialog, and `Build -> Run` the class, now it will work!

If you see the console log, it contains exactly the command you would use when running on command line:

```
----jGRASP exec: java --module-path /Users/<user>/Downloads/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib --add-modules javafx.controls HelloFX

 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

I guess the next step will be running a more complex project...

Comment: As you typed this, I received independent confirmation of this solution, which does work for me.   You typed it up much better than I was going to.   Thank you!

Comment: Good to know, hopefully this short _guide_ can be useful to others too!

Answer (score 1):

Try simply creating a launcher with only a main Method. It could look something like this:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;

public class MyAppLauncher {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Application.launch(MyApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

(you can leave the old main Method unused in your App for the time-being)
This worked for me with JDK 13 & JavaFX 13 & Eclipse 2019-12 under Ubuntu.
(I created the Project using "new/Maven Project/Simple Project" and then just added JavaFX, Logging & other stuff as dependencies in pom.xml, which all landed on the Classpath. Only the JDK was on the Modulepath)
No need to bother about Java Modules.

If that works, you can take time to learn about Java Modularisation another day...
...and remember to vote for this Answer. :-)